# Converting $\frac{7}{27}$ from base-10 to base-3 and base-12

Tags: elementary-number-theory

**Problem:** How might I convert the base-10 fraction $\frac{7}{27}$ into it base-3 and base-12 decimal expansions?

**My work:** Is $\frac{7}{27}$ precisely equal to $0.314$ in base-12? First I converted both nominator and denominator into base $B$, and then I performed division operations on that base $B$ too. But I am stick. Any ideas?

Comment: Please show your work...

Comment: Do your results compare with what I have given in my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your second question:

$$(0.314)_{12}=3\cdot \frac{1}{12}+1\cdot \frac{1}{12^2}+4\cdot \frac{1}{12^3}=...$$

You can finish the computation

Comment: so your answer is yes?  What about base 3 convertion ?

Comment: Once you do the computation, if the result is $7/27$ then the answer is yes, otherwise, the answer is not. I'm only using the definition of a number written in a base $b$: $(0.a_1a_2a_3...)_b=a_1(1/b)+a_2(1/b^2)+a_3(1/b^3)...$

Comment: @Ba'as Do you understand how the base-12 part worked?

Comment: @crash not really....

Comment: @Ba'as Then why would you try to get the base-3 part before understanding the base-12 part? The answer explains clearly the base-12 part...

Comment: I want to compare my results with yours :)

Comment: @Ba'as You're always welcome to post what you have tried within your question.

Answer (score 1):

**In base 3:**
$$
(.021)_3 = 0\cdot\frac{1}{3}+2\cdot\frac{1}{3^2}+1\cdot\frac{1}{3^3}=\left(\frac{7}{27}\right)_{10}
$$
**In base 12:** 
$$
(.314)_3 = 3\cdot\frac{1}{12}+1\cdot\frac{1}{12^2}+4\cdot\frac{12}{3^3}=\left(\frac{7}{27}\right)_{10}
$$
Does that make sense?